# How do configure ZSH commands substition to not use backticks (`)?

Tags: zsh, configuration, dot-files

I only want `echo $(date)` to return the date not the backticked version.

```
echo $(date) # should return Wed Mar 6 09:50:41 EST 2019
echo `date` # should return `date`
```

Comment: Backticks are part of the grammar, it would be strange if you could disable them. Use single quotes around the string you want to print instead, that would stop the backticks from being special in the shell. I'm not turning this into an answer as I don't know all the ins and outs of the `zsh` shell.

Comment: I did not know about single quotes. that's good enough for me.

It was mostly about when I do git commits and want to add markdown inline.

Comment: @JoshBeauregard if you type `git commit` without `-m`, you actually get a text editor (`vi` on older systems, `nano` on newer), and then you don't have to worry about magic characters

Comment: I have vi set as my editor bit sometimes I just want to make a small commit faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap the backticks in strong quotes to divest them of their subshelly powers:

```
$ echo '`echo`'
`echo`
```

Beware, though, the contraction wrapped in strong quotes:

```
$ echo 'I can't process this.'
> Oh whoops that ">" means we're still in a strong quote.
I cant process this.
Oh whoops that ">" means were still in a strong quote.
```

Comment: Did Gandalf write this?

Comment: You can see the author below and to the right of any question or answer.